# Ajax news-open function doesn't work for php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've bought the "Sonorama" website template and there is ajax function for opening window with news.
But I need to take the news content dynamically from MySQL, so I have to open a **.php** file. But it works only for **.html** files.
Could someone please help me what should I edit to make this working?
Thanks!

HTML:

```
<li id="news?id=1" class="last-news"> <!-- Type One Thumb on Top, PHP, doesn't open -->
                                <div class="news-info">
                                    <h1>ZIMNÍ KONCERTY SE ZNOUZECNOSTÍ</h1>
                                    <p>Začátkem roku si po dlouhé době opět zahrajeme se Znouzecností.</p>
                                    <div class="news-date">4.1.2016</div>
                                </div>
                                  <div class="news-thumb">
                                    <img src="img/img-news1.png" alt='img' />
                                </div>
                            </li><!-- end Type One -->

                            <li id="news-02.html" class="last-news"> <!-- Type Two Thumb on Bottom, HTML, works -->

                                <div class="news-thumb">
                                    <img src="img/img-news2.png" alt='img' />
                                </div>

                                  <div class="news-info">
                                    <h1>NOVÉ PÍSNIČKY</h1>
                                    <p>Připravujeme několik nových písniček, které již brzy můžete slyšet na dalších koncertech.</p>
                                    <div class="news-date">3.12.2015</div>
                                </div>
                            </li><!-- end Type Two -->
```

AJAX FUNCTION:

```
/* Dynamic Window Ajax Content */
"use strict";

var $actual2= null;
var obert2=false;
$(".last-news").click(function() {
        obre2($(this).attr('id'));
        $actual2=$(this);
});

function obre2(quin2){
    $.ajax({
        url: quin2,
        success: function(data) {                   
            $('.news-content').html(data);
            $(".news-content").hide(0)
            $('.news-window').hide(0)   
            tanca2();
            canvia2();  
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#news-show').offset().top - (200) }, 500, function(){
                $('.news-window').show(0);
                $('.news-window').css('height','0');
                $('.news-window').animate({height:760}, 1000,function(){
                    $('.news-window').css('height','760');
                    $(".news-content").fadeIn("slow");
                });             
            });
        }
    });
}
/**/
function canvi2(quin2){
    var obert2=true;
    $.ajax({
        url: quin2,
        success: function(data) {                   
            $('.news-content').html(data);
            tanca2();
            canvia2();
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#news-show').offset().top - (200) }, 500, function(){
                $('.news-window').show(0);
                $('.news-window').animate({height:760}, 1000,function(){
                    $('.news-window').css('height','760');
                    $(".news-content").fadeIn("slow");
                });             
            });
        }
    });
}
/**/
function tanca2(){
    $(".close2-btn").click(function() {
        $(".news-window").slideUp("slow");
        $(".news-content").fadeOut("slow");
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#anchor01').offset().top }, 1000);
        obert2=false;
    });
}
function seguent(){
    if($actual2.next().hasClass('end')){
        $(".news-content").fadeOut("slow");
        $actual2=$($('.start').next());
    }else{
        $(".news-content").fadeOut("slow");
        $actual2=$($actual2.next());
    }
    if($actual2.hasClass('isotope-hidden')){
        seguent();
    }else{
        $(".news-content").fadeOut("slow");
        canvi2($actual2.attr('id'));
    }
}
function enrera(){
    if($actual2.prev().hasClass('start')){
        $(".news-content").fadeOut("slow");
        $actual2=$($('.end').prev());
    }else{
        $(".news-content").fadeOut("slow");
        $actual2=$($actual2.prev());
    }

    if($actual2.hasClass('isotope-hidden')){
        enrera();
    }else{
        $(".news-content").fadeOut("slow");
        canvi2($actual2.attr('id'));
    }
}
function canvia2(){
    $('.news-next').click(function() {
        seguent();
    });
    $('.news-prev').click(function() {
        enrera();
    });
}
```

Comment: If you are using  simple jQuery AJAX, it does not matter what file extension you are requesting to, as long as it returns a valid output. I have not used **Sonorama** or whatever that is, but the code you posted is simple ajax. Try a php  file instead of an html file. That should work. BTW, where is `quin2` defined?

Comment: @SajibAcharya I've tried to open PHP file, but it doesn't work, window doesn't even open.. And about `quin2` - I have no idea, I've copied all I could.

Comment: First you need to know how your code works. Otherwise you would not be able to modify any stock template code. Things will not work magically. Do you know how jQuery AJAX works?